# What's the difference between packaging a WPF app or providing a published .exe directly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Is there a difference in:
a) When we provide a published .exe setup (output) of a WPF application, and
b) When we package it into a Windows Application Package Project.

I'm asking in terms of Visual Studio IDE. Couldn't really find an answer to this on web.
Thanks in advance for any valuable inputs you may provide.

Best,
Shanks :)

Comment: If you have a single project then publish it in these two ways, what are the differences you feel when deploying to another machine? If you demonstrate your effort to start an interesting discussion, others are more willing to participate.

Answer (score 0):

`.exe` files are essentially converting code into binary executables, while packaging is to set up a running environment for `.exe` files and to make it easier to run on other computers.

And the packaging will be used in the execution of the program so `dll`, `ocx`, etc. contained, and automatically register the used controls at installation time.

Simply put the package includes `.exe` and exe (runtime environment).